# AWS SAM ScheduledEvent error: "Parameter ScheduleExpression is not valid"

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-event-bridge

I'm trying to setup an EventBridge Scheduled Event for my Lambda Function using the SAM CLI.

My desired cron expression is:

```
cron(0 0 * * ? *)
```

My template.yml file:

```
Events:
  ScheduledEvent:
    Type: Schedule
    Properties:
      # Every day at 0:00
      Schedule: cron(0 0 * * ? *)
```

I've tried setting the cron expression on the AWS console and it's considered valid.

I've tried these other expressions in my `template.yml` file:

```
cron(0 0 * * ? *)
cron(0 0 * * * *)
cron(0 0 ? * * *)
cron(0 1 * * ? *)
cron(1 1 * * ? *)
0 0 * * ? *
"cron(0 0 * * ? *)"
```

but they always return the same error when I try to deploy the stack.

What's the error in my cron expression?

Comment: Can you try with quotes? so `"cron(0 0 * * ? *)"`

Comment: Also tried with quotes, still not working.
I'm going to update the question.

Comment: For reference, the issue is also being tracked here: https://github.com/aws/serverless-application-model/issues/2392

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deployed a sample Node.js function from this repository https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-lambda-developer-guide/tree/main/sample-apps/blank-nodejs after adding the event config to its template.
This is the event config I added:

```
Events:
  ScheduledEvent:
    Type: Schedule
    Properties:
      # Every day at 0:00
      Schedule: cron(0 0 * * ? *)
```

It worked and after that I tried to deploy my original function (with no changes to its template). Now my function was deployed successfully.